# colour an entire table row

Tags: tables, color

I have a table and I would like to highlight some rows.

I am using:

```
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
```

and:

```
\rowcolor{gray!50}
```

which produces:

[image]

I want to highlight the entire row with a solid block of colour,

```
like this!
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

---

MWE:

```
\begin{table*}[ht]
  \centering
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1mm}
  \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
    \hline\hline
    \thead{Name} & \thead{Observing\\Frequency\\(MHz)} & \thead{Mean Standard Deviation of\\On-Pulse Phase Bins} & \thead{Peak Systematic\\Variability} & \thead{Average Systematic\\Variability} & \thead{Noisy\\Variability} \\
    \hline
\rowcolor{gray!50}
B1747 & 1400 & 8.83 & 281.00 & 0.95 & 8.68 \\
B1747 & 2030 & 3.61 & 6.15 & 0.09 & 3.66 \\
B1747 & 1500 & 2.37 & 5.47 & 0.19 & 2.35 \\
B1347 & 820 & 1.44 & 4.59 & 0.09 & 1.43 \\
\rowcolor{gray!50}
B1921 & 820 & 5.46 & 34.23 & 2.56 & 3.87 \\
C1921 & 1500 & 5.16 & 12.00 & 1.12 & 4.86 \\
D1921 & 1400 & 4.93 & 22.66 & 1.84 & 3.96 \\
B1921 & 2030 & 2.82 & 14.01 & 1.29 & 2.25 \\
\hline
  \end{tabular}
\caption{caption}
\label{var_table}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: You should really provide a complete minimal working example (MWE), which reproduces your issue, begins at `\documentclass`, ends at `\end{document}` and includes every necessary package. With the question as it is, I can only guess that you try to add additionalspace inbetween columns, either with `@{}` or by changing the length of `tabcolsep`.

Comment: ...most likely `@{\hspace{5pt}}` or something similar.

Comment: I have strictly no problem with the code you posted. There must be something else not in the post.

Comment: Good to see, that you posted a MWE, but you're lacking the necessary packages, the `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. (and what is `\thead`?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To add space between the columns in a table using `\rowcolor` you should use `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5mm}` for a uniform space change. If the changes shouldn't be uniform, you might insert additional columns which only insert space (using `<{\hspace{5mm}}`). In the latter case, you have to use additional `&`s to add the empty columns.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
Wrong:
\begin{tabular}[]{@{\hspace{5mm}}c@{\hspace{10mm}}c@{\hspace{5mm}}}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{gray!50}a&b\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\\good:
{
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5mm}
\begin{tabular}[]{cc}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{gray!50}a&b\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\\not uniform:
{
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0mm}
\begin{tabular}[]{c<{\hspace{7mm}}c<{\hspace{12mm}}c<{\hspace{5mm}}}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{gray!50}&a&b\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

In the first table it won't work, while the second and third tables gives the desired results:

[image: results]

Comment: Thank you! Anyway to remove the faint but noticeable line between the cells?

Comment: @user1551817 Those spaces are normal for `\rowcolor`. They are there even without any changes in spacing. They are the fault of the pdfviewer. Open the pdf with Xpdf and they are gone. They shouldn't be there after printing.

Answer (score 3):

With the `tabularray` package is simple:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[ht]
\centering
\begin{talltblr}[
    note{a} = {Mean Standard Deviation}
            ]{
    hline{1,Z}=1pt, hline{2}=0.6pt,
    colspec = {X[l,m]   X[c,m, si={table-format=4}]
                        X[c,m, si={table-format=1.2}]
                        X[c,m, si={table-format=3.2}]
                        X[c,m, si={table-format=1.2}]
                        X[c,m, si={table-format=1.2}]
               },
    row{1} = {font=\small\bfseries},
            }
Name    & {{{Observing Frequency (MHz)}}}
                & {{{MSD\TblrNote{a} of On-Pulse Phase Bins}}}
                        & {{{Peak Systematic Variability}}}
                                    & {{{Average Systematic Variability}}}
                                            & {{{ Noisy Variability }}}     \\
\SetRow{bg=gray8}
B1747   & 1400  & 8.83  & 281.00    & 0.95  & 8.68  \\
B1747   & 2030  & 3.61  &   6.15    & 0.09  & 3.66  \\
B1747   & 1500  & 2.37  &   5.47    & 0.19  & 2.35  \\
B1347   &  820  & 1.44  &   4.59    & 0.09  & 1.43  \\
\SetRow{gray8}
B1921   &  820  & 5.46 &  34.23 & 2.56  & 3.87  \\
C1921   & 1500  & 5.16 &  12.00 & 1.12  & 4.86  \\
D1921   & 1400  & 4.93 &  22.66 & 1.84  & 3.96  \\
B1921   & 2030  & 2.82 &  14.01 & 1.29  & 2.25  \\
\end{talltblr}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of the package `nicematrix` provides (when the key `colortbl-like` is in force) commands similar to those of the classical `colortbl` to color rows, columns and cells.

You will have the expected output even if you use `@{\hspace{...}` to increase the space between two columns.

Moreover, you won't see thin white lines, whatever PDF viewer you use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[ht]
  \centering
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1mm}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{c@{\hspace{2cm}}ccccc}[colortbl-like]
    \hline\hline 
    \RowStyle{\bfseries}
    \thead{Name} & \thead{Observing\\Frequency\\(MHz)} & \thead{Mean Standard Deviation of\\On-Pulse Phase Bins} & \thead{Peak Systematic\\Variability} & \thead{Average Systematic\\Variability} & \thead{Noisy\\Variability} \\
    \hline
\rowcolor{gray!50}
B1747 & 1400 & 8.83 & 281.00 & 0.95 & 8.68 \\
B1747 & 2030 & 3.61 & 6.15 & 0.09 & 3.66 \\
B1747 & 1500 & 2.37 & 5.47 & 0.19 & 2.35 \\
B1347 & 820 & 1.44 & 4.59 & 0.09 & 1.43 \\
\rowcolor{gray!50}
B1921 & 820 & 5.46 & 34.23 & 2.56 & 3.87 \\
C1921 & 1500 & 5.16 & 12.00 & 1.12 & 4.86 \\
D1921 & 1400 & 4.93 & 22.66 & 1.84 & 3.96 \\
B1921 & 2030 & 2.82 & 14.01 & 1.29 & 2.25 \\
\hline
  \end{NiceTabular}
\caption{caption}
\label{var_table}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]